# Node.js: is it possible to use express and nodal together?

Tags: node.js, express

In node.js, express is MVC framework, and Nodal is REST API framework which makes it really easy to create web API.
However I am just wondering in the project using express if I can use Nodal too, so that I can build API very fast.

Roughly it seems impossible or much hard to keep both of them together, but wondering if someone has experience to do this successfully.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run both frameworks however each framework is bound to an http or https server that listens over a specific port, and because they use the same protocol, you will run into issues.

So what you can do is run your express server on port 80 or 443, then run your API server with nodal on port 8000.  Then forward traffic to api paths from express to nodal (simply website.com:8000).

Comment: Well, so what you mean is I will have to so far have 2 projects separately, and will have 2 servers running?

Comment: You can have everything in the same project, but create two separate servers.  Maybe look into using NGINX as your proxy, run express on port 8000 and api on port 8100 then use NGINX to forward requests to the proper servers.